# DataGridView and parse string from XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a table with 4 rows and 6 columns. I need, depending on the letter, to insert it in the necessary line in turn. Here is a visual drawing, as it should be. That is, the letters are inserted in turn in the columns. But also when inserting, it determines which letter is now inserted into the corresponding string. If possible, then read the line from the XML file. If not, you can implement assigning a tag to each letter. DataGridView I need to paint each cell containing the letter. That they do not merge and be readable. Sorry for my English

```
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Firm>Toyota</Firm>
    <ImageC>cruzer.jpg</ImageC>
    <Model>Land Cruiser</Model>
    <Year>2017</Year>
    <st>A</st>
    <sec>B</sec>
    <third>C</third>
    <fourth>B</fourth>
    <fifth>C</fifth>
    <sixth>A</sixth>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Firm>testestsetsetse</Firm>
    <ImageC>cruzer.jpg</ImageC>
    <Model>HereModel</Model>
    <Year>2017</Year>
    <table>ABCBCA</table>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

[image: Example paint]

Comment: Show us your xml.

Comment: Added.I show 2 options how it must be.Top is for every letter and bottom is all in one string.

Comment: It's the whole application description and it's too broad, please describe the problem which you have faced with.